# How to do an api with firebase functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use firebase-functions. The idea is to create some sort of a functions nodejs api. I have the following code in my config.ts

```
import * as CORS from 'cors';
export const cors = CORS({ origin: true });

import * as express from 'express';
export const app = express();

app.use(cors);

//// Initialize Firebase ////

import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const db     = admin.firestore();
export const auth   = admin.auth();
```

and the api.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import { app } from './config';

app.get('/converter', (req, res) => res.send('success'));

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My expectation is that when I navigate to https://us-central1-XXXX.cloudfunctions.net/converter, it should display the string `success`. Unfortunately all I get is this:

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /converter from this server.
```

How can I do this better?

Comment: Yes I really need it! Firebase deploy logs no errors. The function deploys correctly. When I trigger it from the firebase console, I get this error ```Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you exported your function from index.js:

```
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

What you told Cloud Functions was that you have an HTTPS endpoint called `api`, and the you're serving it entirely through an express app.  Since your function is called `api`, your URLs will all be prefixed with `api`. So try this:

```
https://us-central1-XXXX.cloudfunctions.net/api/converter
```